# Blender number pad hot keys and zoom help! Not working

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, interface, navigation

I'm fairly new to blender and i'm really stuck, i've followed countless YouTube tutorials and searched the web but nothing i've tried works.

1. First off my number pad hot keys don't seem to be working, I have been needing to use the 'period' key and also '0' but when I press these hot keys nothing happens! Even if I go into the view tab and press frame selected it doesn't work. And because I'm having issues with the navigation i can't then just press . to take me to the asset i've lost.
2. Secondly, I am having real issues with the zoom getting stuck, I know this is an issue that a lot of people have posted about but nothing seems to be working for me, I've changed the auto depth ETC and still nothing.

Basically i'm having issues that a lot of people seem to be encountering and posting fixes but non are working for myself.

Hope someone can help.
Ant

Comment: does your keyboard have a num lock?  Is it on?  On many keyboards, the numpad doubles as a specials pad and the keys behave differently if numlock isn't on.

Comment: Use the included batch file in the Program Files folder to start blender with factory settings. If that doesn’t help, report it as a bug. There is no configuration case where clicking the menu option to frame selected should not work, *unless of course nothing is selected to frame.*